# Downgrade Python to 3.5 - conflict with ppft/xz

Tags: python, anaconda, ppft

I would like to downgrade Python from 3.6 to 3.5. `conda` tells me the following:

```
$ conda install python=3.5.0 -n myenv
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - ppft -> python 3.6* -> xz 5.2.*
  - python 3.5.0*
```

Now knowing any of the packages in the first line, `conda info ppft` gives me `ResolvePackageNotFound`. `conda info xz` gives me a long list of versions, the latest of which is

```
xz 5.2.3 0
----------
file name   : xz-5.2.3-0.tar.bz2
name        : xz
version     : 5.2.3
build string: 0
build number: 0
channel     : defaults
size        : 667 KB
arch        : x86_64
date        : 2017-08-18
license     : Public-Domain, GPL
license_family: GPL2
md5         : 585458787b315ac1e5fb3a1ee71cad75
noarch      : None
platform    : linux
url         : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64/xz-5.2.3-0.tar.bz2
dependencies:
```

How do I continue - what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

First off `ppft` is not listed in the default anaconda directory but in conda-forge. But if you take a look at the files in that directory you will find there are versions for python 3.5. Furthermore according to the homepage for [xz](https://tukaani.org/xz/), it is compatible with python 2 or 3.

One option would be to remove the conflicting libraries, downgrade to 3.5, and then reinstall the libraries later. For example

```
conda uninstall ppft xz
conda install python=3.5 -n myenv
conda install xz
conda install -c conda-forge ppft
```

Comment: This will give me `RemoveError: Error: this 'remove' command cannot be executed because it
would require removing 'conda' dependencies'

Comment: Which command? The first? I'm trying to replicate the problem on my end, but I am able to remove both ppft and xz without issue. Can you post the entire message? This exact series of commands was successful for me.

Comment: Now it will give me a useful dependency list instead of the Error it would throw out before. The problem is that each of the two packages has roughly 30-50 packages dependent on them that would have to be removed if I go the removal way.